# premake c++ "hello world" error

Tags: c++, premake

I'm trying to get a premake4 helloworld c++ working
but get an error when invoking make with release config after the makefile is created with premake. (I'm using clang on osx 10.9.4)
Calling `make config=release` produces:

```
ld: internal error: atom not found in symbolIndex(...
```

If I add the "Symbols" flag to the release flags everything works fine.
But this of course creates debug symbols.

premake4.lua:

```
solution "cpp_hello_world"
configurations { "Debug", "Release"}

project "cpp_hello_world.out"
kind "ConsoleApp"
language "C++"
files { "**.cpp" }

buildoptions { "-std=c++1y" } 

configuration "Debug"
defines { "DEBUG" }
flags { "Symbols" }

configuration "Release"
defines { "NDEBUG" }
flags { "Optimize" }
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea why it does not work like in the standard example?
http://industriousone.com/post/typical-c-project-0

complete output using `make config=release verbose=1`:

```
==== Building cpp_hello_world.out (release) ====
Creating obj/Release
mkdir -p obj/Release
main.cpp
c++ -MMD -MP -DNDEBUG   -O2 -std=c++1y  -o "obj/Release/main.o" -c "main.cpp"
Linking cpp_hello_world.out
c++ -o ./cpp_hello_world.out obj/Release/main.o  -Wl,-x
ld: internal error: atom not found in symbolIndex(__ZNSt3__1lsINS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIcT_EES6_PKc) for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [cpp_hello_world.out] Error 1
make: *** [cpp_hello_world.out] Error 2
```

Comment: in buildoptions, what does `c++1y` mean?

Comment: http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html "C++1y implementation status
Clang 3.4 and later implement all of the Draft International Standard (see most recent publicly available draft) of the upcoming C++ language standard..."

Comment: it does not change anything about the build error if I remove the flag

Comment: It works here on windows with MinGW... Can you provide the output of `make config=release verbose=1` to have extra information.

Comment: Can you try the command `c++ -o ./cpp_hello_world.out obj/Release/main.o` (without the `-Wl,-x`) ? maybe related to [x-link-flag-causing-link-errors-on-mac-osx-10-9-bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24921221/x-link-flag-causing-link-errors-on-mac-osx-10-9-bug)

Comment: that seems to be the problem! if I remove `-Wl,-x` it compiles succesfully. but how can I fix this in premake?

Comment: I suggest to look directly on there forum. [how-remove-flags-ldflags](http://industriousone.com/topic/how-remove-flags-ldflags)

Comment: thanks a lot! I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the error on my mac, OS X 10.10.2, using Premake4. The problem is with your project name, which shouldn't have a `.out` extension. Try renaming project to "cpp_hello_world" in your premake4.lua file instead.

i.e. line 4 should read:

```
    project "cpp_hello_world"
```

I can test and troubleshoot on a VM on 10.9.4 if you continue to encounter problems after making this change - let me know!

Comment: Did you try to build in release mode? Changing the project name to `project "cpp_hello_world"` didn't change anything. I get the same error message as the one I posted in the question.