# Error installing PyLucene JCC on OSX

Tags: python, macos, solr, lucene, clang

I am having trouble installing PyLucene JCC on Mac OSX.

I dowloaded the latest version of JCC from apache lucene site and fallowed the instruction to install it  using the command

```
python setup.py build
```

But I am getting the following error while installing

```
ld: internal error: atom not found in symbolIndex(__ZN7JNIEnv_13CallIntMethodEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDz) for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'c++' failed with exit status 1
```

I have tried following the instruction given on the official site of adding the flag `"-framework", "Python" to the LFLAGS value`  when installing on mac OSX or using the `export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments` and `export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments` before runnig the install command to ignore the warnings while build. But none of them are working.

The full trace of error is

```
found JAVAHOME = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
found JAVAFRAMEWORKS = /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework
Loading source files for package org.apache.jcc...
doc/serialized-form.html...
Building index for all the packages and classes...
Generating javadoc/overview-tree.html...
Generating javadoc/index-all.html...
Generating javadoc/deprecated-list.html...
Building index for all classes...
Generating javadoc/allclasses-frame.html...
Generating javadoc/allclasses-noframe.html...
Generating javadoc/index.html...
Generating javadoc/help-doc.html...
running build
running build_py
writing /Users/harshsingh/Documents/Codes/IR/jcc/jcc/config.py
copying jcc/config.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/jcc
copying jcc/classes/org/apache/jcc/PythonVM.class -> build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/jcc/classes/org/apache/jcc
copying jcc/classes/org/apache/jcc/PythonException.class -> build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/jcc/classes/org/apache/jcc
running build_ext
building 'jcc' extension
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -    DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -dynamiclib -D_jcc_lib -DJCC_VER="2.    21" -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.    jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin -I_jcc -Ijcc/sources -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c jcc/sources/jcc.cpp -    o build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/jcc/sources/jcc.o -DPYTHON -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-write-strings
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-dynamiclib'
jcc/sources/jcc.cpp:197:16: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int'
      [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    int hash = PyObject_Hash(arg);
        ~~~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -    DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -dynamiclib -D_jcc_lib -DJCC_VER="2.    21" -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.    jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin -I_jcc -Ijcc/sources -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c jcc/sources/JCCEnv.    cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/jcc/sources/JCCEnv.o -DPYTHON -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-write-strings
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-dynamiclib'
c++ -Wl,-x -dynamiclib -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/jcc/sources/jcc.o build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/jcc/sources/JCCEnv.    o -o build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/libjcc.dylib -L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib -ljava -    L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server -ljvm -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.    jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server -Wl,-S -install_name @rpath/libjcc.    dylib -current_version 2.21 -compatibility_version 2.21
ld: internal error: atom not found in symbolIndex(__ZN7JNIEnv_13CallIntMethodEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDz) for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'c++' failed with exit status 1
```

I am really lost now and any help will be really great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If rebuilding from source still ends up giving the same errors, you could probably try the following approach.

Seems like there is a bug with running the clang++ command (below) with the -x flag, on OSX 10.9+ (referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24921221/x-link-flag-causing-link-errors-on-mac-osx-10-9-bug))

```
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -    DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -dynamiclib -D_jcc_lib -DJCC_VER="2.    21" -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.    jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin -I_jcc -Ijcc/sources -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c jcc/sources/JCCEnv.    cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/jcc/sources/JCCEnv.o -DPYTHON -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-write-strings
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-dynamiclib'
c++ -Wl,-x -dynamiclib -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/jcc/sources/jcc.o build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/jcc/sources/JCCEnv.    o -o build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/libjcc.dylib -L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib -ljava -    L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server -ljvm -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.    jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server -Wl,-S -install_name @rpath/libjcc.    dylib -current_version 2.21 -compatibility_version 2.21
```

Run the clang++ command again without the -x flag and then run:

```
python setup.py build
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here - from pyLucene-dev:

> You must ensure that the compiler used to build Python is the same as the compiler you're using. If you did not build Python then it's likely you're htting a clang/gcc mismatch and you need to rebuild Python from sources, using the same compiler as you're using to build JCC.

Comment: Hi @Sid, I did that and build python from source. And it worked well. I also found another quickfix kind of thing. I installed python using homebrew and then I removed the "-framework", "Python" from the LFLAGS value in the setup.py script in JCC install package. This removed the force use of system python in setup and used the python version I had installed using homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

The clang problem is fixed as given [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PYLUCENE-38). However, its not pushed in the PyLucene latest(as of May 2018) version(v6.5). However, you can still get the next build(v7.2) of Pylucene from [this](https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/lucene/pylucene/7.2.0-rc1/) link. Using Pylucene 7.2.0 fixed the issue for me.