# Atom not found in symbol index when installing PyLucene on Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: python, c++, macos, python-2.7, lucene

I'm trying to install PyLucene, and when I do "pushd jcc" and "python setup.py build", I get this error:

ld: internal error: atom not found in symbolIndex(__ZN7JNIEnv_13CallIntMethodEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDz) for architecture x86_64

What could be the problem? I have the Java 1.7 SDK installed. I installed Python using "brew install Python" and I added /usr/local/bin before /urs/bin in my PATH so that this version of Python 2.7.8 is used and not the one shipped by Apple (2.7).

Here are some lines that get outputted on the "python setup.py build" command:

```
found JAVAHOME = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home
found JAVAFRAMEWORKS = /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework
```

and

```
writing /Users/administrator/Downloads/pylucene-4.9.0-0/jcc/jcc/config.py
copying jcc/config.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/jcc
copying jcc/classes/org/apache/jcc/PythonVM.class -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/jcc/classes/org/apache/jcc
copying jcc/classes/org/apache/jcc/PythonException.class -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/jcc/classes/org/apache/jcc
running build_ext
building 'jcc' extension
clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -dynamiclib -D_jcc_lib -DJCC_VER="2.20" -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin -I_jcc -Ijcc/sources -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c jcc/sources/jcc.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/jcc/sources/jcc.o -DPYTHON -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-write-strings
clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -dynamiclib -D_jcc_lib -DJCC_VER="2.20" -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin -I_jcc -Ijcc/sources -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c jcc/sources/JCCEnv.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/jcc/sources/JCCEnv.o -DPYTHON -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-write-strings
clang++ -Wl,-x -dynamiclib -undefined dynamic_lookup -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/jcc/sources/jcc.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/jcc/sources/JCCEnv.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/libjcc.dylib -L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib -ljava -L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server -ljvm -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server -Wl,-S -install_name @rpath/libjcc.dylib -current_version 2.20 -compatibility_version 2.20
ld: internal error: atom not found in symbolIndex(__ZN7JNIEnv_13CallIntMethodEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDz) for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'clang++' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to build Python from source with the same compiler, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570125), or alternatively build it in NO_SHARED mode.  The latter is the default for the pylucene homebrew formula.

Comment: Does "brew install python" build Python from source? The link doesn't really explain how to build python from source with the same compiler.